# Not able to deserialise boolean values properly through Jackson

Tags: jackson, boolean, deserialization, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I am using the following jackson mapper in my project.

```
org.codehaus.jackson jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13
```

My issue that whenever I try to convert a json string into an object, I am not able to map the boolean values properly. Its a very peculiar problem.
If my attribute name starts with *"is"* e.g `"isFlag":true`, the jackson is not reading it. If I change the attribute name to `"Flag":true`, correct object is getting created.

Reference Json :

```
{"ticketNumber": "0970897760","chartPrepared": true,"isFlag": true}
```

Reference Class :

```
class TestClass {
        String ticketNumber;
        boolean chartPrepared;
        boolean isFlag;

        public boolean isChartPrepared() {
            return chartPrepared;
        }
        public void setChartPrepared(boolean chartPrepared) {
            this.chartPrepared = chartPrepared;
        }
        public boolean isFlag() {
            return isFlag;
        }
        public void setFlag(boolean isFlag) {
            this.isFlag = isFlag;
        }
        public String getTicketNumber() {
            return ticketNumber;
        }
        public void setTicketNumber(String ticketNumber) {
            this.ticketNumber = ticketNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Function :

```
TestClass obj = mapper.readValue(text, TestClass.class);
System.out.println(obj.getTicketNumber()+" "+obj.isChartPrepared()+" "+obj.isFlag());
```

Actual Output:

```
0970897760 true false
```

Expected Output:

```
0970897760 true true
```

Comment: Change `isFlag` to`flag` in your Json, or your method `isFlag` to `isIsFlag`

Comment: Thanks for the reply BusyAnt. I figured out a better solution.  Explicitly Adding @JsonProperty("isFlag) in the TestClass solved this problem. @JsonProperty("isFlag")
  boolean isFlag;

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the reply BusyAnt. I figured out a better solution.  Explicitly Adding @JsonProperty("isFlag) in the TestClass solved this problem.

```
@JsonProperty("isFlag")
boolean isFlag;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because Jackson expect `getXxx()` even for boolean, so it's always better to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, because when you generate the getter/setter in any IDE, you only get `isFlag()` for `boolean` primitive type, but if is `Boolean`, you will have `getFlag()`.